# PHP - UNSET Elements in a Deep Mixed Index/Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a mixed index/associative array in PHP that can, in theory, be infinitely deep because some elements may have 'children' arrays. I attach a slimmed down example. The php array is derived from some JSON data.

I want to search on a given key/value pair and to delete any elements matching that pair at the index level.

So for example, in the array below, I wish to search for the key of 'formId' and a value of '44' and to delete elements such that $array[0][0][0][0] and $array[0][1] are removed. Obviously I will then need to re-number the array.

I need to be able to search on any key/value pair... only one pair at a time is necessary... that is to say that the above example of 'formId' of '44' might be 'viewId' of '16' next time.

I have tried numerous ways to do this, with iterators, recursive foreach loops, &$reference keys but I just cannot seem to get it right.

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [formId] => 0
        [subId] => 0
        [viewId] => 0
        [id] => 0
        [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [formId] => 1
                [subId] => 0
                [viewId] => 16
                [id] => _st_node_5328_0_0
                [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (                                           
                        [formId] => 1
                        [subId] => 0
                        [viewId] => 16  
                        [id] => _st_node_3838_0_0_0
                        [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                            (
                                [formId] => 44
                                [subId] => 
                                [viewId] => 16   
                                [id] => _st_node_947_0_0_0_0
                            )

                            [1] => Array
                            (   
                                [formId] => 7
                                [subId] => 
                                [viewId] => 16
                                [id] => _st_node_947_0_0_0_1

                            )

                            [2] => Array
                            (
                                [formId] => 3
                                [subId] => 
                                [viewId] => 16
                                [id] => _st_node_947_0_0_0_2 
                            )

                            [3] => Array
                            (
                                [formId] => 10
                                [subId] => 
                                [viewId] => 16
                                [id] => _st_node_947_0_0_0_3
                            )

                            [4] => Array
                            (
                                [formId] => 9
                                [subId] => 
                                [viewId] => 16                                                             
                                [id] => _st_node_947_0_0_0_4
                            )

                            [5] => Array
                            (
                                [formId] => 8
                                [subId] => 
                                [viewId] => 16
                                [id] => _st_node_947_0_0_0_5
                            )

                            [6] => Array
                            (
                                [formId] => 6
                                [subId] => 
                                [viewId] => 16
                                [id] => _st_node_947_0_0_0_6
                            )

                            [7] => Array
                            (                    
                                [formId] => 5
                                [subId] => 
                                [viewId] => 16
                                [id] => _st_node_947_0_0_0_7
                            )

                            [8] => Array
                            (
                                [relId] => 167
                                [formId] => 4
                                [text] => Laptop Computers
                                [subId] => 
                                [viewId] => 16
                                [id] => _st_node_947_0_0_0_8
                                [isActive] => 
                            )

                            [9] => Array
                            (
                                [formId] => 1
                                [subId] => 
                                [viewId] => 16
                                [id] => _st_node_947_0_0_0_9
                            )
                        )
                    )

                    [1] => Array
                    (
                        [formId] => 1
                        [subId] => 0
                        [viewId] => 1
                        [id] => _st_node_3838_0_0_1
                    )

                    [2] => Array
                    (
                        [formId] => 1
                        [subId] => 0
                        [viewId] => 11
                        [id] => _st_node_3838_0_0_2
                    )

                    [3] => Array
                    (
                        [formId] => 1
                        [subId] => 0
                        [viewId] => 12
                        [id] => _st_node_3838_0_0_3
                    )

                    [4] => Array
                    (
                        [formId] => 1
                        [subId] => 0
                        [viewId] => 13
                        [id] => _st_node_3838_0_0_4
                    )

                    [5] => Array
                    (
                        [formId] => 1
                        [subId] => 0
                        [viewId] => 14
                        [id] => _st_node_3838_0_0_5
                    )

                    [6] => Array
                    (
                        [formId] => 1
                        [subId] => 0
                        [viewId] => 110
                        [id] => _st_node_3838_0_0_6
                    )
                )
            )

            [1] => Array
            (
                [formId] => 44
                [subId] => 0
                [viewId] => 144
                [id] => _st_node_5328_0_1
            )

            [2] => Array
            (
                [formId] => 10
                [subId] => 0
                [viewId] => 26
                [id] => _st_node_5328_0_2
            )

            [3] => Array
            (
                [formId] => 9
                [subId] => 0
                [viewId] => 9
                [id] => _st_node_5328_0_3
            )

            [4] => Array
            (
                [formId] => 8
                [subId] => 0
                [viewId] => 8
                [id] => _st_node_5328_0_4
            )

            [5] => Array
            (
                [formId] => 7
                [subId] => 0
                [viewId] => 25
                [id] => _st_node_5328_0_5
            )

            [6] => Array
            (
                [formId] => 6
                [subId] => 0
                [viewId] => 6
                [id] => _st_node_5328_0_6
            )

            [7] => Array
            (
                [formId] => 5
                [subId] => 0
                [viewId] => 5
                [id] => _st_node_5328_0_7
            )

            [8] => Array
            (
                [formId] => 4
                [subId] => 0
                [viewId] => 4
                [id] => _st_node_5328_0_8
            )

            [9] => Array
            (
                [formId] => 3
                [subId] => 0
                [viewId] => 3
                [id] => _st_node_5328_0_9
            )

        )

    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The idea

Since you want to unset elements, you definitely want to pass the `$array` into the function as a reference (`&$array`).

You want to use recursion to allow you to dig as deep as necessary based on the actual array.

You loop over all elements of the array and the first thing you do is check whether an element is an array. If it is, you check if that subarray matches your criteria. If it does, you remove it. If it doesn't you invoke the function with the same `$key`, `$value` pair on that subarray.

### The code

```
function removeMatching($key, $value, &$arr) {
    // Iterate over all $arr elements
    foreach ($arr as $i => $subarr) {

        // Skip all elements that are not arrays
        if (is_array($subarr)) {

            // Check if the sub-array matches the criteria
            if (isset($subarr[$key]) && $subarr[$key] === $value) {

                // Remove it from the main array if it does
                unset($arr[$i]);
            } else {

                // If the sub-array didn't match the criteria
                // Check if it contains any other matching sub-arrays
                removeMatching($key, $value, $arr[$i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Apply like this:

```
$array = []; // your array

removeMatching('formId', 44, $array);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Thanks Kuba - Works a treat!. I had tried various 'foreach' techniques but I think the "$arr as $i" was the subtle change I needed! Thanks very much for the assistance!